# Riseup vpn not removing after removed?

Tags: vpn

So i tried to use to use Rise Up VPN from the Ubuntu store but..... it doesn't work and i have tried to remove it but the icon is still in the application menu and I have no idea how to remove it, nor have I found anything on it.

Comment: How did you install it? Did you delete it through the Ubuntu Store? Or by `sudo apt-get purge rapidvpn`?

Comment: I installed it from the Ubuntu store, and deleted it from the Ubuntu store but it still stays